# ¿Puedo pasar una tupla como parámetro por valor y referencia?

Tags: python, paso-por-referencia, paso-por-valor

Me ha surgido una duda de Python estudiando las tuplas. Soy consciente de que normalmente los tipos de datos **inmutables** (Numéricos, Textos, Booleanos..) se pasan por valor y los tipos de datos **mutables** (Listas, Diccionarios, Conjuntos...) por referencia.
Después de estar investigando un poco he visto en varios sitios un poco información opuesta, por eso me gustaría saber: **¿Un tupla solo se puede pasar como parámetro por valor o también por referencia?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una pregunta que no es tan simple. En python decimos que tenemos *variables*, pero sería más correcto decir que tenemos *objetos* a los que accedemos siempre *"por referencia"*.

Así si hacemos:

```py
a = 1
b = a
a = 2
```

Tenemos dos objetos, `1` y `2`, que son de tipo `int` (números enteros). Estos objetos los referenciamos con dos etiquetas, `a` y `b` que, acostumbrados a otros lenguajes, llamamos *"variables"*.

Si razonásemos estas asignaciones, en realidad veríamos que `a` empieza apuntando a `1`, luego `b` apunta al mismo objeto que `a`, y luego `a` apunta a `2`, `b` sigue apuntando a `1`. No existe una variable con memoria reservada a la que asignamos un valor.

Entrando en lo que es la pregunta, en python no existe los conceptos de stack de memoria o de una heap, como en otros lenguajes. **El objeto existe o se crea en algún momento anterior a que hagamos su referencia**. Habrá objetos mutables e inmutables, pero siempre se usarán por referencia, nunca se pasan por valor.

Por ilustrar un poco más, cuando digo que *"El objeto existe o se crea en algún momento anterior a que hagamos su referencia"* quiero señalar que hay objetos que existen siempre, aunque no los uses. Por ejemplo, los números enteros del -5 al 256 son tan comunes que el intérprete los tiene creados desde el inicio. Cualquier uso que les des, siempre será como referencias.

Un modo de comprobarlo:

```py
[i for i,j in zip(range(-100, 1000), range(-100, 1000)) if id(i) == id(j)]
```

Si tienen el mismo `id()`, entonces se trata del mismo objeto.

Por ilustrar un poco más, aquí tenemos dos ejemplos que pueden parecer similares:

```py
>>> a = (1,2,3,4)
>>> a += (5,6,7)
>>> print(a)

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a += [5,6,7]
>>> print( a )

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

La diferencia es que con las tuplas, la referencia `a` apunta a otra tupla, mientras que con la listas, `a` sigue siendo la misma lista:

```py
>>> a = (1,2,3,4)
>>> print(id(a))
>>> a += (5,6,7)
>>> print(id(a))

192021604
189519828

>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> print(id(a))
>>> a += [5,6,7]
>>> print(id(a))

189780876
189780876
```